# pagination with javascript and xml

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I am currently parsing an xml file and getting contents to display in a table of 5 columns and x number of rows depending on the number of items are in the xml file. Unfortunately, everything is appearing on the page and I need to implement pagination in my javascript to handle hundreds of records from the xml file. I was thinking 50 items per page or 20 rows at 5 columns each. Below is the code I have so far:

Javascript:

```
function generateTables(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();      
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/test_102.xml",false);    
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("vids");
    var xmlContent = "<table class='table' id='videos' border='0'>";
    var rows = parseInt(x.length/5 + .6)
    var count = 0;
    var z = 0;
    //Pagination idea. We can get the x.length value which is the total tags that we have. We can divide that by 50 to get teh number of pages we have. Then we can simply simply each on a pge and we will knwo the # of pages in a variable.
    //rows
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        //This will handle if there is an uneven amount of columns.
        if ((count + 5) > x.length)
            {
            z = x.length - count
            }
        else 
            {
            (z = 5)
            }
        xmlContent += '<tr>'

        //columns
        for (y=0;y<z;y++) {
            var title = x[count].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var vidPath = x[count].getElementsByTagName("vidPath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var png = x[count].getElementsByTagName("pngPath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var gif = x[count].getElementsByTagName("gifPath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            xmlContent += "<td align='center'>" + title;
            xmlContent += "<br /><a href='"+ vidPath;
            xmlContent+="'><img src='"+ png +"' width='50%'";
            xmlContent+= "onmouseover=\"this.src='"+gif+"'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='"+png+"'\"/></a></td>";         
            count++
            }
        xmlContent += '</tr>'
    }
    xmlContent += "</table>";
    //document.write(rows)  
    content.innerHTML = xmlContent;

}
```

This is the html that I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My tables</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/records.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">Page Title</div>
    <div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
   generateTables();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now this is working in that it will display all the records in the correct rows/columns. I just need to implement paging with what I have so far. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't create a proper `XMLHttpRequest`, which should use the `onreadystatechange` Event to then check `if(xmlhttp.readyState == && xmlhttp.status == 200)`. Also, your `xmlhttp` variable is global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Here it is:

```
function generateTables(start){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();      
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/test_102.xml",false);    
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("vids");
    var xmlContent = "<table class='table' id='videos' border='0'>";
    var columns =5;
    var count = 0;
    var z = 0;
    var rows = 10;

    //Pagination stuff
    var totalContent = x.length;//total number of content       
    var noPerPage = rows*columns;//Number of content in one page    
    var noOfPage = 0;//Holds number of pages

    if(totalContent%noPerPage == 0) {
        noOfPage = Math.floor(totalContent/noPerPage);
    }
    else {
        noOfPage = Math.floor((totalContent/noPerPage)+1);
    }

         //if total content is less than number of content in one page
    if(totalContent < noPerPage) {
        if(totalContent%columns == 0) {
            rows = Math.floor(totalContent/columns);
        }
        else {
            rows = Math.floor((totalContent/columns)+1);
        }
        noOfPage = 1;
    }

    //if total content is less than number of content in one page
    if(totalContent < noPerPage) {
        if(totalContent%columns == 0) {
            rows = Math.floor(totalContent/columns);
        }
        else {
            rows = Math.floor((totalContent/columns)+1);
        }
        noOfPage = 1;
    }

    var whichPage = (start/noPerPage)+1;//Current page number

    var pagination = 5;//To show page numbers, better to keep odd number like 3,5,7 etc
    var midPagination = Math.floor(pagination / 2);
    var html = ""
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        //This will handle if there is an uneven amount of columns.
        if ((start + 5) > x.length)
            {
            z = x.length - start
            }
        else 
            {
            (z = 5)
            }
        if(x[start]) {
        xmlContent += '<tr>'
        }       

        //columns
        for (y=0;y<z;y++) {
            var title = x[start].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var vidPath = x[start].getElementsByTagName("vidPath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var png = x[start].getElementsByTagName("pngPath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var gif = x[start].getElementsByTagName("gifPath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            if(x[start]) {
                xmlContent += "<td align='center'>" + title;
                xmlContent += "<br /><a href='"+ vidPath;
                xmlContent+="'><img src='"+ png +"' width='50%'";
                xmlContent+= "onmouseover=\"this.src='"+gif+"'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='"+png+"'\"/></a></td>";         
                }
            else {
            xmlContent += "<td> </td>";
            }
            count++
            start++
            }
        xmlContent += '</tr>'
    }

      //to generate pageinition
        xmlContent += "<tr>";
        xmlContent += "<td colspan='"+columns+"' align='center'>";

        if(whichPage > pagination) {
            xmlContent += "<a onclick='doPagination("+noPerPage*(whichPage-1-pagination)+")' style='cursor:pointer'><<</a> ";
        }
        if(whichPage > 1) {
            xmlContent += "<a onclick='doPagination("+noPerPage*(whichPage-1-1)+")' style='cursor:pointer'><</a> ";
        }

  //generate page numbers
    var fno = whichPage - midPagination;
    var lno = whichPage + midPagination;

  if(fno < 1 &&  noOfPage > pagination) {
       fno = 1;
       lno = pagination;
  }
  else if(fno < 1 && noOfPage <= pagination) {
      fno = 1;
      lno = noOfPage;
  }
  else if(lno > noOfPage && noOfPage <= pagination) {
   fno = 1;
            lno = noOfPage;       
        }
  else if(lno > noOfPage && noOfPage > pagination) {
      lno = noOfPage;
      fno = (lno - pagination) + 1;
  }

  //loop pages numbers
    for(var k=fno;k<=lno;k++) {
        if(whichPage == k) {
            xmlContent += "<b>"+k+"</b> ";
        }
        else {
            xmlContent += "<a onclick='generateTables("+noPerPage*(k-1)+")' style='cursor:pointer'>"+k+"</a> ";
        }
    }

    if(whichPage < noOfPage) {
        xmlContent += "<a onclick='generateTables("+noPerPage*(whichPage-1+1)+")' style='cursor:pointer'>></a> ";
    }
    if(whichPage <= (noOfPage - pagination)) {
        xmlContent += "<a onclick='generateTables("+noPerPage*(whichPage-1+pagination)+")' style='cursor:pointer'>>></a>";
    }

    xmlContent += "</td>";
    xmlContent += "</tr>";

    xmlContent += "</table>";

  //Add generated html content
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlContent;
    //document.write(rows)  
    //content.innerHTML = xmlContent;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XMLHttpRequest` to increment `onreadystatechange` after the user clicks a button, then have the Server send the information back that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Render all of the rows like you do now and use JavaScript (suggesting jQuery) to hide all rows beyond the amount you would like to display (eg. 50).

Add a pager with a next and prev button eg. A-Tags like

```
<a href="#" id="pager_prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" id="pager_next">Next</a>
```

Now store your current pager state and the maximum pager state in variables

```
var pagerState = 0;
var maxPagerState = ceil(jQuery('table#videos').find('tr').length / 50);
```

Use a start-up code like this

```
// On document ready
jQuery(function() 
{
    // Get all rows
    var rows = jQuery('table#videos').find('tr');

    // Hide all rows
    rows.hide();

    // Select the first fifty rows
    rows.slice(0, 50).show();
});
```

And bind onClick events to the pager buttons

```
// On click event: prev
jQuery('#pager_prev').click(function() 
{
    if(pagerState > 0)
    {
        pagerState--;

        // Get all rows
        var rows = jQuery('table#videos').find('tr');

        // Hide all rows
        rows.hide();

        // Select the desired rows and show them
        rows.slice(pagerState * 50, (pagerState + 1) * 50).show();
    }

    return false;
});

// On click event: next
jQuery('#pager_next').click(function() 
{
    if(pagerState < maxPagerState)
    {
        pagerState++;

        // Get all rows
        var rows = jQuery('table#videos').find('tr');

        // Hide all rows
        rows.hide();

        // Select the desired rows and show them
        rows.slice(pagerState * 50, (pagerState + 1) * 50).show();
    }

    return false;
});
```

I haven't tested it but I think it's a good point to start.

Edit: There could be a problem when slicing the rows within the pager-next-function. But test it first.